# Skype 4.2 shows incorrect time of contacts at Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype, time, contacts, timezone

I am using Skype 4.2 in my Ubuntu 14.04 system. I am facing a problem at the Skype. When I see other contacts time in the chat window or at their profile, it shows wrong time. It calculates the time based on UTC+0, but my timezone is UTC+6. I have checked my system's timezone:

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

and it shows:

```
Asia/Dhaka
```

How can I change the Skype timezone to my timezone? I can't see any GUI option to set timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by doing:

- First, changed the my profile timezone to "My Computer" from `"Skype->Profile->Edit your profile->Show full profile->Timezone"` from a windows installation. Like this:

  [image]
- Then I have removed my current installation of Skype on my Ubuntu 14.04 (`sudo apt-get remove skype`) . Renamed `.Skype` to `1.Skype` at `/home/<user>/`.
- Re-installed Skype. And It's all fine.